# Problem finding limit value with squeeze theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I have been working on a limit:  $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3^n}} $$
using squeeze theorem to try and put it between 2 limits. I found the bigger limit ($\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{3}} = 1 $), but can't really find the smaller one. For n equals 1 I get the limit:  $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3}} $ . Anything smaller is a negative value and anything bigger is bigger than the main limit. Any help is appriciated and sorry for messy post, this is my first time on the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in order to apply the squeeze theorem your inequalities don't need to hold for all $n$, it is sufficient if they hold for all $n\geq n_0$ for some $n_0$ (as finitely many terms doesn't influence the convergence). In this case we can take $n_0=2$, then we have for all $n\geq2$:$$\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3^n}\geq\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3^2}$$
and therefore $$\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3^n}}\geq\sqrt[n]{\frac{2}{9}}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1$$

Comment: Better if a complete answer using the theorem can be provided.